# CRC Matrix realization step by step

Tags: matrix, transformation, crc

I am looking for a little help with the transformation of a 7/4 crc. 
With 4 bit Datainput and 3 bit CRC-code.

It took me now 3 days of researche and i found for example this document:

http://apt.cs.manchester.ac.uk/ftp/pub/apt/papers/MGrymel_TVLSI10.pdf
or
http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=1234528&tag=1

But I have really to admit that i am a person that works best with concrete examples and so I don't really get how i get from my starting point to the result.

Has someone maybe a good document, a forum discussion or something like that?
Or could help me by himself?

I need just a more plastic description of what is to do.

Comment: That sounds like a [(7,4) Hamming code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming(7,4)), which can correct any one-bit error and detect any two-bit error. It doesn't sound like a CRC. A CRC can be applied to any number of bits, not just four.

Comment: I mean CRC, i know you can apply it to any number of bits, so you can apply it to a 4 bit input :)